# Bootstrap-select does not submit selection

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

**I have this form:**

```
<script src="./bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<form action="rec.php" name="submit" method="post">
    <select name="all[]" class="form-control">
        <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        ?>
        <option value="details<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    ?>
    <input type = "hidden" name="infos[]" value="<?=$i?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" vale="submit" name="submitit">
</form>
```

**rec.php:**

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

When I submit the form, I get only Arrays of `infos[]` and nothing about `all[]`. When I remove `bootstrap-select` and resubmit the form, I get all the results.

How to fix bootstrap-select in order to solve my problem?

I am using [Bootstrap-select v1.10.0](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select).

Comment: When you say "remove bootstrap-select", you mean you are removing the script tag pointing to the library?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `script` tag after the `form` for just before the closing of the body tag?

Comment: Why is the select name "all[]" and not "all". all[] implies that you expect the select to have multiple values, but, as i understand it, the select can only have one value.

Comment: @JECarterII yes exactly.

Comment: @Arnolio i want to get multiple value.

Comment: @Nandan i already tried it , i get the same problem.

Comment: to use `<select>` with bootstrap-select you should create select with `.selectpicker` class: `<select class="selectpicker">`

Comment: @JisMaxi Specify the method in the form. Example ( method = "post")

Comment: @Nandan already specified

Comment: @Banzay the last version do not need that.

Comment: @JisMaxi Try changing the name all[] to something else.

Comment: @JisMaxi any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have left a comment but it doesn't allow me to post pretty output. I replicated your code

index.php

```
<script src="bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<form action="rec.php" name="submit">
    <select  name="all[]" class="form-control">
        <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            ?>
            <option value="details<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        ?>
        <input type = "hidden" name="infos[]" value="<?=$i?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitit">
</form>
```

rec.php

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre>";
```

It looks like you're trying to implement a multi select, however it's clear to me that the select i'm seeing is just a regular select, and a regular select can only have one value

This is the output that i see:

```
array(4) {
  ["all"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "details1"
  }
  ["infos"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "7"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [9]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
  ["submitit"]=>
  string(6) "submit"
  ["Phpstorm-2043c6b"]=>
  string(36) "........." <- ignore this
}
```

Can you explain to me what about that output is different than what you expected?

Note:
The documentation you linked to suggested the class on the select should be: **selectpicker**

And you need this line:

```
<script>
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
```

However this leads to the error:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)
- Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)

You need to at least include Jquery to make the multi select work. (I haven't tested this)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
```